# recursive repetition of a string

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to write a function that will take 2 strings, p and k. It will check the lengths of p and k and repeat the letters in p consecutively until the result word is of the length of k. ex: Let p = 123 and k = 45678. Then result word = 12312, because length of k is 5. So the chars of p are consecutively repeated until end word reaches length of k. My code below does not work as I want it to:

```
repString::[Char]->[Char]->[Char]
repString [] (y:ys)         =[]
repString (x:xs) []         =[]
repString (x:xs) (y:ys)
 |length(x:xs)<length(y:ys) =(x:xs)++x:repString (xs) []

main = do
print $ repString "123" "45678"
```

I am not sure how to make this work, because every time it reaches the end of x:xs, it will see an empty string and then it will fulfill the appropriate base case and terminate. I don't know how to make it go back to the beginning of (x:xs) and start printing again.

Comment: have a look at [`cylce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) and [`take`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to write is something like:

```
repString :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
repString [] k = []
repString p [] = []
repString p k
   | length p <= n = p ++ repString p (drop (length p) k)
   | otherwise     = take n p
   where n = length k
```

But would be better written as:

```
repString :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
repString p k = take (length k) (cycle p)
```

Comment: this should be faster `repString p k = zipWith const (cycle p) k` and pointfree `repString = zipWith const . cycle`

Comment: Should be a *lot* faster for infinite lists, No_signal!